# how to sum array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

how to add fare if the data generated like this ? so that there can be the total number of tariff
how to add fare if the data generated like this ? so that there can be the total number of tariff

```html
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
           
            [TARIFF] => 0
           
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
         
            [TARIFF] => 0
           
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            
            [TARIFF] => 29500
            
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
           
            [TARIFF] => 20500
            
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           
            [TARIFF] => 14500
            
        )

)
```

Comment: `array_sum(array_column($array, 'TARIFF'));`

Comment: `array_reduce($array, function($runningTotal, $value) { $runningTotal += $value['TARIFF']; return $runningTotal; }, 0);`

Comment: Or just get your database query to do it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to sum your array:

- You can use `array_sum()` in combination with `array_column()`
- You can use a `foreach`
- You can use `array_map()`
- You can use `array_reduce()` - (Mark Baker)

#### array_sum() and array_column()

```
$total = array_sum(array_column($array, 'TARIFF'));
```

#### foreach

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $total += $value['TARIFF'];
}
```

#### array_map()

```
$count = array_sum(array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value['TARIFF'];
}, $array));
```

#### array_reduce() - Thanks to Mark Baker

```
array_reduce($array, function($runningTotal, $value) {
    $runningTotal += $value['TARIFF'];
    return $runningTotal;
}, 0);
```

Sources:

- [array_sum() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)
- [array_column() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- [foreach - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [array_map() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [array_reduce() - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_sum()` along with `array_column()`

**Example**

```
$a = array(
    "a"=>52.2,
    "b"=>13.7,
    "c"=>0.9
);
echo array_sum($a);
```

---

**In Your case**

```
array_sum(array_column($arrayName, 'TARIFF'));
```

---

**Links to reffer**

1. [`array_sum` in W3School.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp)
2. [`array_column()` in W3School.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp)